# POST API not working in express /node.js with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

I am learning nodejs..i make a post api with static data with mysql database
My config.js file :

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"test"

})

module.exports =con;
```

and my index.js file:

```
    const express = require('express');
const con = require('./config')

const app = express();

app.post('/', (req, res) => { 
   const data = {
      name: "xyz",
      email: "xyz@gmail.com",
      mobileno: "88888888",
      Address: "xyz place"
   }
   con.query('INSERT INTO biodata SET ?', data, (err, result, field) => {
      if (err) {
         res.send("error data not inserted")
      }
      console.log(result)
      res.send(result);
   })
})

app.listen(5000)
```

when i am running the code it giving me error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/ 404 (Not Found)
```

i am doing POST api but it giving me abov error

Comment: How did you access the URL?

Comment: Its static data in index.js

Comment: "i am doing POST api but it giving me abov error" — The error says you are making a GET request. We can't tell why the request you are making is GET when you seem to think it is a POST because you haven't shared the code for it.

Comment: @Vicky I mean did you browse the URL via web browser, or make a request through code with selected method, or use Postman?

Comment: Thats my problem i am making POST but it showing GET error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes via web browser

Answer (score 0):

Try running your server and copy paste the following into the terminal:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/'
```

The command above will make a post request to your service from the terminal. If you haven't installed curl, [download it here](https://curl.se/download.html).

Answer (score -1):

Accessing a URL such as yours (http://localhost:5000/) via web browser will always use GET method. If you want to make a request with POST, you have to use other way.

For example, you can write a code that makes POST request, or you can simulate a request to your end something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).